# MongoDB query match for several subfields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

After spending several hours trying to solve this, and not finding my answer in the docs of on StackOverflow, I'm opeing a question here.

I have a large collection (3.5M docucuments) and want to filter out those that match on a specific combination of sub fields.

E.g. the documents look like:

```
{
 _id:...,
 ...<a number of fields>
 "ML":[
  {
   "_id": ...,
   ... <more fields>
   "Op": [
    "_id": ...,
    "Pr": {
     "P94": <number>,
     "P95" : ...,
     ...,
     "P145": <optional and number>
    }
    {...},
    ...
   ],
  {...},
  ...
 ],
 ...
}
```

So P145 is sometimes there, sometimes not.

I want to find al documents that have a "ML.Op.Pr" with ***both*** "P94":8 *and* P145 exists.
I've tried and failed (as I get no/0 results):

- .find({"ML.Op.Pr":{"P94":8,"P145":1})
- .find({"ML.Op.Pr":{$and[{"P94":8},{"P145":1}]}})

I've also tried $and as a first step,

- .find({$and[{"ML.Op.Pr.P94":8},{"ML.Op.Pr.P145":1}]})

but since both ML and Op are an array with multiple entries, it returns too many results. I need both Pr's to be set in the same array element.

As you can see I'm first trying to find where P145 = 1, because when I replace it with $exists it doesn't parse at all.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use nested `$elemMatch` for each sub-array divisions in order to get the desired result.

```
db.collection.find({
  "ML": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "Op": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "Pr.P94": 8,
          "Pr.P145": {
            "$exists": true
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground sample execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sZpS-xQdkJG)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (Christmas ) but thanks